# Two ranges/ color-scales within one seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, numpy, seaborn, data-visualization, heatmap

I was doing quite some research, but couldn't find a satisfying solution yet.

I'm trying to build a heatmap using seaborn.
As my dataset is a bit volatile in a lower range (0-20) but reaches up to 7000 using only one color-scale for all of the data doesn't allow a good graphical interpretation. That's why I thought about using two scales, two different color-spectrums.

I would like to merge those two heatmaps into one:

[image]

What works so far is that I get both axes (scales) displayed in my plot, but when it comes to plotting the data only the last active axis is taken into account. The upper range is not considered.

[image: heatmap with two scales][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTOEn.png)

I have also tried to split the data set according to the spectrum, but this was not working.
Here is my code:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(merged, classes)


vmax = np.amax(merged)

ax1 = sns.heatmap(df, vmin = 25, vmax = vmax, cmap = "crest", )
ax2 = sns.heatmap(df, vmin = 0, vmax = 25, cmap = "flare", )

plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Method")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to plot both parts together, you can update the colormaps such that the "over" and the "under" color are set to invisible ("none"). The "over" color is used for values that are larger than `vmax`. The "under" color is used for values below `vmin`.

Optionally, you can set negative padding for the first colorbar to have both colorbars closer together.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter

# first create some test data
data = gaussian_filter(np.random.rand(50, 50), sigma=5)
data -= data.min()
data *= 2 / data.max()
data = np.where(data < 1, data*25, (data ** 3) * 25)

# adapt the colormaps such that the "under" or "over" color is "none"
cmap1 = plt.get_cmap('crest').copy()
cmap1.set_under('none')
cmap2 = plt.get_cmap('flare').copy()
cmap2.set_over('none')

ax1 = sns.heatmap(data, vmin=25, cmap=cmap1, cbar_kws={'pad': -0.02})
sns.heatmap(data, vmin=0, vmax=25, cmap=cmap2, ax=ax1)

plt.show()
```

[image: heatmap with two different colormaps]

Comment: works perfect!! just need to find better color scales! But thanks a lot. saved me quite some time :))

Comment: Maybe one more question. As I now learned that it is possible to modify and change the colormaps quite easily, I wondered if it might be possible to 'cut it in half'. Using the same color scheme for both scales, but cut into two parts. Using for example only the green part in between 0-80 of the greenish/blueish scale on the right for the lower range and what is left of the scale for the bigger, upper range. cheers!!

Comment: You could use a `norm = matplotlib.colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=0, vcenter=25)` and then `sns.heatmap(data, cmap="crest", norm=norm)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the two `Axes` to plot beforehand, and then use the `ax` argument when calling `sns.heatmap` in order to tell seaborn which `Axes` should have which colormap.

Example (using mock data):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

values = np.random.uniform(0, 7000, size=(50, 50))
vmax = np.amax(values)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

sns.heatmap(values, ax=ax1, vmin=25, vmax=vmax, cmap="crest")
sns.heatmap(values, ax=ax2, vmin=0, vmax=25, cmap="flare")

for ax in (ax1, ax2):
    ax.set_xlabel("Time")
    ax.set_ylabel("Method")

plt.show()
```

Resulting figure:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer! Maybe merging is not the best term for what I'm trying to say. In the end I want a single plot over the same dataset which distinguishes between the lower and the upper range, so that I have to different color scales with two different ranges within the same plot :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Colormap class that uses both other Colormaps

```python
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class SplitCMap(mpl.colors.Colormap):
  def __init__(self, name, vmin, vsplit, vmax, N=256):
    super().__init__(name, N)
    self.lowcmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap('flare')
    self.highcmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap('crest')
    self.split_level = (vsplit-vmin) / (vmax-vmin)
    self.scale_low = 1.0 / self.split_level
    self.scale_high = 1.0 / (1.0 - self.split_level)
  def mapcolor(self, v, **kwds):
    if v < self.split_level:
      return self.lowcmap(v * self.scale_low, **kwds)
    return self.highcmap((v-self.split_level)*self.scale_high, **kwds)
  def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):
    if isinstance(args[0], (int, float)):
      self.mapcolor(args[0], **kwds)
    return [self.mapcolor(v, **kwds) for v in args[0] ]

df = pd.DataFrame(merged, classes)

vmax = np.amax(merged)

cmap = SplitCMap('split', 0, 25, vmax)
ax = sns.heatmap(df, cmap=cmap)

plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Method")

plt.show()
```